# Is it possible to lift up an inlne element inside its block container?

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
 line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      <label>Text</label>
  </div>
```

In this case the `.container`'s height is calculated to `24px` and that of the `label` to about `20.6px` (Chrome). Seemingly, the `label` is verically centered inside the `.container`. Is it possible instead to lift `label` up by 2-3px inside its container (to put it in other words, to align it vertically to the top line of the container)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `transform`, like so:

```css
.container {
 border:1px solid red;
}

label{
 transform:translateY(-3px);
 display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <label>Text</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position to manipulate anything inside the container as you wish